# Get value return of function form file gs to use in function file script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 2 files, 1 code .gs file and 1 .html file. I want get value return of function in file gs and call it in function file html script?

---

code in file funcs.gs:

```
function func1(){

  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urldb);
  var ws =  ss.getSheetByName("SettingAccount");
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

  return data;

}

function func2(){

  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urldb);
  var ws =  ss.getSheetByName("SettingAccount");
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

  return data;

}
```

---

code in file index.html:

```
<script>

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showValue).func1();

function showValue(data){

var list = google.script.run.func2();

}

</script>
```

---

> results list --> "undefined"

I want to get value of "func2" to use in function "showValue", can anyone help with this?

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: When you create a function in two separate files in the same project you can just call them, but Aidan's answer is correct in this case, I misunderstood the intention the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the first function correctly:

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showValue).func1();

This will call showValue(data) and the data parameter will be filled in with the return value from func1().

Your second call is incorrect - the return from google.script.run.func2() is not the return value from func2(). You can get the return value from func2 by supplying a withSuccessHandler as you did in the call to func1.

Just change it to run the same way:

```
function showValue(data){

   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(list) {

     // do something with the list here

   }).func2();

}
```